# Any Sample program in AS400 where we can redirect the output of a command to a file

Tags: ibm-midrange

We have a requirement for monitoring setup.

Monitoring team says that if we can redirect the output of a command in AS400 to a logifle then they will be able to do the setup the monitoring alert.

I am new to AS400. Could anyone please let us know if there is any sample program which actually redirects the output of a command to a logfile.

Comment: It's been a long time since I touched an AS400 so my vague ideas don't really warrant a proper answer, but you might try the OUTFILE command: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fdspfd.htm & http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdbp%2Frbafourfof.htm

Comment: `OUTFILE` is not a command, but it is a common parameter on many CL commands.

Comment: Which command are we talking about?

Comment: Please describe the process you need to monitor.  Aside from the OUTFILE() parameter on many commands, there are APIs which can be called directly to get this sort of information.  IBM i Navigator allows you to set monitors for certain events.  Triggers can be set on tables, table changes can be logged to journals.  If you describe what it is you need to monitor you'll probably get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the broad answer is "it depends".

Most CL commands produce output in one or more of three methods. If a command allows more than one of these methods, it will have an [`OUTPUT()` parameter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frbam6%2Frbam6outputexpand.htm).  If your command allows `OUTPUT(*outfile)` which will write information to [database](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdbp%2Frbafodbf.htm) physical file member as you specify in the `OUTFILE()` parameter, and optionally the `OUTMBR()` parameter.  You can look up your command's syntax [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fclfinder%2Ffinder.htm).  The output file formats for various commands is documented [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frbam6%2Frbam6clfiles.htm).  A few commands may allow output to go to a [stream file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fifs%2Frzaaxstmfile.htm) in the [IFS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fifs%2Frzaaxwhatifs.htm).

If a command has print output, but not an *outfile option, you may be able to:

- [override the print file to a database file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fovrdbf.htm), before your command, by using

  OVRDBF
- or copy the spool file to a database file, after your command, by using the [CPYSPLF command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fcpysplf.htm)